# Angular directive and SVG

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

so, this is a little complicated.

I have a directive that loads an SVG file based on some criteria. It is a large directive so I won't be posting it here as it does not affect my issue, you just need to know it exists.
In that directive I have a template file that has this bit of HTML:

```
<div ng-include="svgPath" onload="loaded()"></div>
```

note the **onload** function. This is called when the SVG has loaded.

Inside this SVG there are some hidden groups that I need to interact with. Because this is changing the DOM I have written another directive, which looks like this:

```
.directive('kdGraphicsRepeater', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            targetElementId: '@kdGraphicsRepeater'
        },
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/graphicsRepeater.tpl.html',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Declare our options
            scope.options = [];

            // Get our target elements
            var target = angular.element(document.getElementById(scope.targetElementId)),
                svg = angular.element(target.find('svg')),
                children = svg.children();

            console.log(target.length);
            console.log(svg.length);
            console.log(children.length);

            // Loop through the SVG children
            for(var i = 0; i < children; i++) {

                // Get the current child
                var child = children[i],
                    childId = child.attr('id');

                console.log(childId);

                // If we have an option
                if (childId && childId.indexOf('options-') > -1) {

                    // Push the name to our options array
                    scope.options.push(childId.replace('options-'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

and the corresponding template looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in options">
    {{ item }}
</div>
```

As you should be able to make out. I am trying to loop through the SVG immediate children and check to see if any of the elements have a partial id match to **options-**. If they do I add them (omitting the "options-" string) to the **scope.options** variable. My template simply loops through them displays them.

The problem is that the SVG has not loaded for this directive and the **console.log(svg.length)** returns 0 for that very reason. I need some way of knowing when the SVG has loaded.
Can someone help me out?

Comment: How about defining a directive for the SVG elements representing those "options"? Those would have a shared scope with the main parent directive so they could easily notify it that they _exist_.

Comment: I'm guessing your directive is being called before svg is loaded?

Comment: @Sergiu the SVG is loaded from a file which I have no control over.

Comment: @ssayyed Yes, this appears to be the issue. I would like it to wait until the SVG has loaded before loading itself.

Comment: But nothing stops you from defining let's say a `circle` directive that runs on every `<circle>` inside said SVG. - What I'm saying is you don't need to change the SVG markup.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not sure about this but maybe try using the ng-if directive by angular.

in your loaded() function, have like a boolean that says its loaded, say its called svgLoaded. use ng-init instead of onload. Make sure this would be the same scope as the one in your svg.

then in your svgPath, bind ng-if to your boolean

```
<"element where you are attaching kdGraphicsRepeater" 
    ng-if="svgLoaded" kdGraphicsRepeater
>
```

Sorry, I'm making assumption that you have same scope, and that is possible to do.